# Do you need to use the $ch variable with cURL?

Tags: curl

Before going any further, I apologize for my ignorance on the subject, I am a newbie.

When using the cURL function, is it required to use the $ch, $output, $f, $url, etc variables or can you name the variables whatever you like (while still defining them the same way)?

My first instinct was I can name them whatever, but all the examples for cURL I see use the standard variable names. Thanks for your answers in advance!

Comment: Please explain which language you are using. Because you are prefixing the variable name with a dollar sign I'm going to guess PHP, in which case you can name the variable whatever you like apart from [these](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php). However a non-descript convention exists that you would call your cURL handle `$ch` so you may as well stick to that, as it will make your code more readable to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always name variables any way you like (restricted by what are valid variable names in the particular language that you use).

Standard variable names are used, so that the reader can guess from the name as to what the inteded use of the variable is.

When you write a function, it looks like this:

```
function printSum($firstArg, $arg2) {
  print $firstArg + $arg2;
}
```

It does not matter, how the variables are named, that you pass to the function. You might even consider, not passing variables at all, but literals:

```
printSum(5, 3);
```

Inside the function, the parameter list `($firstArg, $arg2)` determines, how the values that where passed to the function are accessed by the function. A function should not know about what goes on outside the function (e.g. how variables are named, etc.).

Comment: Correct but I'd always prefer `$curlHandle` over `$ch`, `$filePointer` over `$fp` and so on. The reader should not *guess* the use from the name, he should *know* it.

Comment: Coming from a mathematical background, it's a guess to me unless I've seen a formal proof. Even if the variable is named `$curlHandle` :)